# Integer value not increment every time

Tags: java, android, int

I declare an int value that tries to increment every button click but some time value not increment and some after 2 or 3 click increment working. I always get log so click event no issue, already tried without static but still not working.

```
public static int TotalScore = 0;

btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initScoreSubmit();
            }
 });

public void initScoreSubmit()
{

        TotalScore++;
        txtTotalPoint.setText("Total Point: " +   String.valueOf(TotalScore));

        settings.set(AppSettings.Key.UserTotalPoint, TotalScore);

        Log.d(TAG, "Total_point "+TotalScore);
}
```

Comment: What submitScore() method do?

Comment: Try making `TotalScore` volatile, or use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: I am not Android expert but did you consider that it is updated in another thread, try to use volatile variable

Comment: there might be because there might be a delay in performing the initScoreSubmit method. So when the button is pressed set the button to disabled and after the Log in initScoreSubmit method set the button to enabled

Comment: volatile value works for me. Can you please tell me why not static value or only int not working

Comment: Why negative  can any one tell me

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the full code, not two methods and a class variable

Comment: FWIW, static variables that are not constants in Android are typically the wrong idea

Comment: cricket_007 please describe in brief.

Comment: cricket_007  i should not paste hole project here And above code should be full example of code am i right?

Comment: *"And above code should be full example of code am i right?"*.  Yes, it should be.  No it isn't.  Please read the link provided by cricket_007.  He was asking for a **minimal**  complete, verifiable example ..... not your entire application.  (Hint: what you posted is not **complete**.)

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please tell me why not static value or only int not working.

Because of the Java memory model.

If one thread writes a variable and another reads the variable, the only ways to *guarantee* that the second thread sees the value written by the first are:

- declare the variable as a `volatile`,
- synchronize the two threads, or
- replace the bare variable with reference to a thread safe class; e.g. an `AtomicInteger`.  The variable should be `final`.

You need to read the Oracle Tutorial on Concurrency, and specifically the sections on synchronization:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html